# How to resolve ANR errors in Google Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I have a Flutter app targeting Android.

Recently I started getting `ANR` errors in Google Play Console pre-launch report. I have not made any significant changes to my app to trigger this, so it seems it is something Google is suddenly doing differently.

Errors are below:

> ANR in com.google.android.apps.messaging;PID: 12100;Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE flg=0x30 pkg=com.google.android.apps.messaging cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/com.google.apps.tiktok.experiments.phenotype.ConfigurationUpdatedReceiver_Receiver (has extras) };

> ANR in com.google.android.dialer;PID: 8132;Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE flg=0x30 pkg=com.google.android.dialer cmp=com.google.android.dialer/com.google.apps.tiktok.experiments.phenotype.ConfigurationUpdatedReceiver_Receiver (has extras) };

> ANR in com.google.android.apps.photos;PID: 9438;Broadcast of Intent {
> act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE flg=0x30
> pkg=com.google.android.apps.photos
> cmp=com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.libraries.phenotype.client.stable.PhenotypeUpdateBackgroundBroadcastReceiver
> (has extras) };

> ANR in com.google.android.apps.safetyhub;PID: 12115;Broadcast of
> Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE flg=0x30
> pkg=com.google.android.apps.safetyhub
> cmp=com.google.android.apps.safetyhub/com.google.apps.tiktok.experiments.phenotype.ConfigurationUpdatedReceiver_Receiver
> (has extras) };

My app does not use `photos`, `dialer`, or any kind of `messaging`. Not even sure what `safety hub` is.

Strangely, only one device is reporting these errors (Pixel 6 arm64 API 31). Other devices Google uses for testing are not reporting this. If there was something wrong with my app I suspect all devices would be getting it (or at least all devices on the same API). Or am I missing something here?

What can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem with Google Play Store testing devices. The problems went away without me  making any significant changes.

Comment: Hi @under, so you just needed to upload a new build, right?

Comment: yes, a new release. store showed these errors. But they went away later. They sort of come and go, seems like a store issue with flutter...

Comment: It's not only an issue with flutter. I don't have flutter and for this issue, reuploading app helped.